# php/mod_fcgid script terminating after 30 seconds

Tags: php, fastcgi

I have the following issue :

When running a long-running php script (file upload) it timeouts after exactly 30 seconds of activity.

Bizzarely, it only occurs in certain cases - the one i know for sure is it always occurs when uploading a file using the stock android browser - android for chrome is ok.

The error in the apache log is :

(70014)End of file found: mod_fcgid: can't get data from http client

I have already increased every apache/fcgi/php setting that i know that are related to timeouts :

## apache

Timeout 180

## fcgi

FcgidIdleTimeout 9600
IPCCommTimeout 520
FcgidIOTimeout 520

## php

max_execution_time = 360

Are there any other settings related to timeout that I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

had the same, had to pass timeout as a parameter in the config, like this:

FastCGIExternalServer /usr/local/bin/php-cgi -socket /tmp/php-fpm.sock -idle-timeout 60 -pass-header Authorization

Comment: Thank you? Can you please specify which config file? I think this setting applies to mod_fastcgi and not mod_fcgid?

Comment: in your vhost, like here: http://whocares.de/fastcgiexternalserver-demystified/all/1/

Comment: Thank you, however this applies only to mod_fastcgi and not mod_fcgid which im using

Comment: Hm. sorry, my bad.